# jQuery speed optimisation

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization

Just after a bit of advice on something that's been bugging me for a while. Is it better for performance to use option 1 or option 2? Or does it not matter at all?

1. `$('.class').removeClass("class");`
2. `$('*').removeClass("class");`

The reason I ask is because I use this code (or similar) quite often and I'm starting to try an optimise my code as much as possible. Both of them work, but which is better?

Comment: Option 1 is better because it will only search for elements with class name '.class' and 2nd option will iterate through all elements.

Comment: general speaking, detailed element lookup rules are better in performance. so `$('*')` slower than `$('.class')` slower than `$('div.class')` slower than `$('#aIDisBest')`

Comment: @Ofcourse , second one is slow as it is like a wildcard search where as earlier looks for only that particular class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a website named jsperf.com where you can post javascript tests. You create many many code snippets, a website that it can test your snippets on and it will tell you, which snippet is the fastest.

I have prepared a test for you, just install Java and run the tests. Option 1 is better :)

http://jsperf.com/select-speed

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a feeling this would be the quicker one but I'm glad I asked now as that link could really come in handy! :)

Answer (score 0):

As `@Sheikh Heera` mentioned in his comment the first one is better, but only if you work with decent browser that has native support for `getElementsByClassName`.

> For class selectors, jQuery uses JavaScript's native
>   `getElementsByClassName()` function if the browser supports it.

Otherwise, which is highly unlikely, it would be the same...

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one is faster. It targets a specific class (id should be faster). Where * targets all elements.